# dismissViewControllerAnimated completion block is not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to dismiss a view controller like this:

```
[composeViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    NSLog(@"Hello"); // Never outputted
}];
```

The view controller is dismissed, but for some reason the completion block is never called.

I have never had any issues with completion block not being called with other view controllers.

This view controller is "special" though, because it's added as a child view controller (which I have not worked with previously in my app). Does this impose any side effects why the completion block is not called?

It's added like this:

```
UIViewController *rootVC = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
[rootVC addChildViewController:self];
[rootVC.view addSubview:self.view];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:rootVC];
```

Comment: `addChildViewController:` actually pushes that view controller onto the navigation stack.  You have to pop it off before that block can fire

Comment: I tried doing `[composeViewController removeFromParentViewController];` (I can see that it's removed from `childViewControllers` property of `rootViewController`) before calling `dismiss...` but the completion block is still not called.

Comment: po the navigation stack, then.

Comment: Why don't you present it using -presentViewController... ? the dismiss method is paired with this one. Or do everything manually. Whrn you present a VC there are lot of properties set in the container: presentingViewController, presentedViewController etc... if you do manually you won't have them valorized

Comment: @Andrea I usually use `-presentViewController...` but this view controller I'm using is from an external source so I don't have any control over how they want it to be presented.

Comment: @CodaFi What do you suggest? Output all view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the issue was: the 3rd party view controller I was using had overridden `- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` without actually calling `completion()`

Answer (score 0):

If you present a modal, is the view controller that receive the message (or the top in hierarchy , I still didn't get that) that handles all the process of adding the child v.c. swapping view etc. It seems that you are doing a mix of the two techniques. Just use one. 
So present it using `- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion` ad dismiss it using dismissViewController let the view controller manages everything.